# how to prevent angularjs dialog from making background scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I maintain a small webapp that uses AngularJS for its front end.

The app just presents a table of information showing the success/failure rates of a bunch of back-end service calls in a framework.

The table is longer than the screen, so it presents a scrollbar so the rest of the table can be seen.

Most of the data in the cells are clickable links that bring up a dialog showing more information about the data in that cell.

What I find is that when I click on that link, it brings up the dialog, but I see that the table in the background has scrolled back to the top of the table.  This is really annoying if I've scrolled well down the table and I want to look at the detail of several nearby cells.

Is there anything reasonable I can do to prevent it from scrolling at all, so that when the dialog is dismissed, the table is at the same scroll location as it was before clicking the link?

This is an excerpt of the HTML that shows one of the clickable cells:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center">title</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <caption style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; font-size: medium;">
                Table Caption
            </caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center">Name</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">5 Minutes</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">15 Minutes</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">60 Minutes</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">180 Minutes</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">Since Midnight</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="name in ratesList track by $index">
                    <td align="right">{{name}}</td>
                    <td align="right" ng-style="{'background-color': computeBgColor(name, 5)}">
                        <div ng-if="totalCount(name, 5) > 0">
                            <div ng-if="failureCount(name, 5) > 0">
                                <a href="#" ng-click="openErrorCounts(name, '5')">
                                    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{totalCount(name, 5)}} records; yellow: {{yellowThreshold(name, 5)}}%; red: {{redThreshold(name, 5)}}%">
                                        {{successRate(name, 5) | percentage:2}} | {{avgTxTime(name, 5) | number:2}} ms
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
```

In the Javascript module, I import the "$uibModal" module for opening dialogs.  Here's a short excerpt showing the definition of that method:

```
        $scope.openErrorCounts  =
        function(name, interval) {
            var modalInstance   = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl:    'errorCountsDetail.html',
                scope:          $scope,
```

Is there a practical way to make this work better?

**Update**:

Just a small update to what the current behavior is:

When I click on the link, I do see the background scroll back to the top, but I also see that the vertical scrollbar disappears entirely.  When I dismiss the dialog, it actually attempts to scroll back to the row I clicked on, but it only makes that line the last line on the screen, which is simply making it visible, not restoring it to its original location.

Adding the $event.stopPropagation() call (in several variations), had no effect on this behavior.

I also monitored the console log while doing this.  The only message that came up was this:

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: dismiss
```

**Update**:

I found when I googled for "how to make angularjs uibModal not scroll the background at all", there appeared to be several cases of people trying to fix the same problem.  I found it hard to follow whether there is a clear solution for this.

I tried one of the simple solutions mentioned, adding this to my page css:

```
    .modal-open {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

I figured this was a longshot, as the answer was -1-ed.  Unsurprisingly, it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding $event.stopPropagation() after click function. So your code for ng-click  will be.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openErrorCounts(name, '5');$event.stopPropagation();">
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{totalCount(name, 5)}} records; yellow: {{yellowThreshold(name, 5)}}%; red: {{redThreshold(name, 5)}}%">
        {{successRate(name, 5) | percentage:2}} | {{avgTxTime(name, 5) | number:2}} ms
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: This had no effect.  I also tried reversing the order of those two calls.